# FilesystemLoader with absolute path on Windows

Tags: symfony, twig, timber

I'm developing a website using Timber/Twig for Wordpress. I would like to render a template with an absolute path on my windows machine (working with Local).

```
$path = "C:\Users\jonas\Local Sites\mywebsite\app\public/wp-content/themes/my-theme/components/example/index.twig";

$context = Timber::context();
Timber::render($template, $context);
```

`Timber::render()` return false and the template isn't rendered, because the `Twig\FilesystemLoader->exists()` function return false. The functions is called in the `Timber\Loader` class.

On Mac it's working fine! If I'm using a relative path like "/components/example/index.twig" it's working fine as well.

It seems that Twig's FilesystemLoader does not work with absolute paths on Windows machines.

Is there a way to make Twig\FilesystemLoader handle absolute paths as well? I get the absolute path via a PHP glob function:

```
$components = glob(__DIR__ . "/components/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
foreach($components as $component) {
    // $component= "C:\Users\jonas\Local Sites\mywebsite\app\public/wp-content/themes/my-theme/components/example";
    $component = $component . "/index.twig";
    $context = Timber::context();
    Timber::render($component, $context);
}
```

Comment: So what is the question here? Why would you want to use an absolute path to render templates anyway?

Comment: The `FilesystemLoader` will look for any existing templates *relative* to the folder you've configured as your views folder, so loading "absolute" paths can't be done by default. Either you will need to register multiple folders or set your views folder to C:\, which is something I would not recommend. [Extra information about changing the template folder](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/template-locations/) or you can always create your own `Loader` I guess

Comment: If all of the results are inside `__DIR__`, why not convert them back to relative paths?